# Can we make Hibernate Interceptors asynchronous

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jakarta-ee, interceptor

I have an application which does auditing and it's low priority, so I don't want user to wait on this auditing piece to complete, can it be configure to be asynchronous?

Comment: This sort of operation doesn't sound entirely germane to the goal of Hibernate Interceptors.  What specifically were you attempting to accomplish with this interceptor?

Comment: Trying to accomplish a similar auditing functionality mentioned here
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AuditLogging but asynchronously. 

I can still change parts of the its private methods to asynchronous calls and achieve the effective end result. But wondering if there is something Hibernate provides out of the box and can be configured, which will make it all look clean and tidy.

PS: I **don't** want to consider using Envers (http://envers.jboss.org)